# Выравнивание по ширине, выделения части текста жирным и меж. абзацный интервал в ExpandableTextView

Tags: android, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

пытаюсь выровнять текст по ширине , выделить часть текста жирным  и изменить меж. абзацный интервал в ExpandableTextView.

1) Пробовал это сделать в string.xml для TextView не получилось

2) Пробовал TextView заменить на WebView не получилось

3) Пробовал TextView заменить на JustifyTextView не получилось

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:expandableTextView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/expand_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        expandableTextView:maxCollapsedLines="1"
        expandableTextView:animDuration="0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/expandable_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
             />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/expand_collapse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

---

string.xml для TextView

```
<string name="aboutDES"> <![CDATA[  <p style="font-size:18px";> <font color="#050015"> <b>Алгоритм шифрования DES</b></font> </p> 
         <p> <font color="#666666"> В данном приложение используется алгоритм шифрования DES т.е. алгоритм для симметричного шифрования. Суть его заключается в следующем чем больше цифр в ключе шифрования тем больше ступеней шифрования каждого символа в отдельности. Например если в ключе 6 символов то каждый символ сообщения будет шифроваться 6 раз, соответственно чем больше символов тем надежнее отправленное сообщение зашифровано, т.е его сложнее будет дешифровать злоумышленнику. Максимально число символов в ключе 32.
         </font></p>
         ]]>
</string>
```

---

string.xml  для WebView

```
<string name="aboutDevelopers">
    <![CDATA[
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
   p {
    text-indent: 10px;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
   }
  </style>
  </head>
 <body style="text-align:justify;color:#666666;background-color:#d1f6f6;font-size:18px;">
  <p>Данное приложение является выпускной квалификационной работой студента Иркутского национально исследовательского университета, обучающегося в институте Высоких Технологий на кафедре Информационной безопасности по специальности Информационная безопасность (Комплексная защита объектов информатизации)</p>
<p><b>Выполнил:</b> студент группы ИБб-14-1 Мельников Данил Алексеевич</p>
<p><b>Научный руководитель:</b> Тюрнев Александр Сергеевич</p>
 </body>
</html>
]]>
    </string>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

В коде нужно сделать следующее:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.aboutDevelopers)))
```

Comment: 1)мне использовать в string, код ,который я предоставил, для WebView? 2)есть ли большая разница  между кодом который вы написали и который я использовал TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.aboutDevelopers))

Comment: @Medaf, 1) да 2) разницы нет, в моём случае я достаю строковый ресурс через `getResources()`, а вы достаёте через метод активити `getString()`, который так же вызывает `getResources()`

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен,но можете попробовать SpannableString для tv

```
Spannable text = new SpannableString("Алгоритм шифрования DES");
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#050015")), 0, text.length(),  Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    text.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setText(text);
```